# Question regarding a paragraph from the book "Sheaves on Manifolds" by Kashiwara and Schapira

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category, $\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{o}}$ be its opposite category and let $\mathscr{C}^{\vee}$ be the category of contravariant functors from $\mathscr{C}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$. The following image is from page 26 of the book *Sheaves on Manifolds* by Kashiwara and Schapira. **Does it contain an error?** It says $\mathscr{C}^{\vee\mathrm{o}}$ is (equivalent to) the category of covariant functors from $\mathscr{C}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$, denoted by $\mathscr{C}^{\wedge}$. Then it says $\mathscr{C}^{\wedge}\simeq\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{o}\vee\mathrm{o}}$.

If this is true then one can conclude that $\mathscr{C}^{\vee\mathrm{o}}\simeq \mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{o}\vee\mathrm{o}}$.

[image: From page 26 of the book *Sheaves on Manifolds* by Kashiwara and Schapira]

Comment: If you rather mean $\mathcal C^{\circ\lor}=(\mathcal C^\circ)^\lor$, then I guess you're right. No need to flip the natural transformations.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that in the book *Categories and Sheaves* by the same authors, $\mathscr{C}^\wedge$ is defined as
$$\mathscr{C}^\wedge:=[\mathscr{C},\mathbf{Set}]^{\rm{op}}$$
and *not* as the opposite category of $\mathscr C^{\vee}$, which would be $[\mathscr{C}^{\rm{op}},\mathbf{Set}]^{\rm{op}}\cong[\mathscr{C},\bf{Set}^{\rm{op}}]$ (actually I fail to see how this is the category of covariant functors into the category of sets). Using the above definition, the claimed isomorphism is obviously true.

Comment: I agree with you that using $\mathscr{C}^{\wedge}:=[\mathscr{C},\mathbf{Set}]^{\mathrm{o}}$ the isomorphism $\mathscr{C}^\wedge\simeq\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{o}\vee\mathrm{o}}$ is true, but I still don't see why they say $\mathscr{C}^{\wedge}$ is the opposite category of $\mathscr{C}^{\vee}$. Is that an error?

Comment: I don't see that either.